# Which open-source java-library provides an easy way to read and write ESRI Shapefiles?

Tags: java, open-source, shapefile

For a project I need to read and write ESRI shapefiles. It should be very easy, as I don't need advanced features. Is something out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GeoTools](http://geotools.codehaus.org/) supports shapefiles via a plugin. GIS is a complicated area and I think what you will find is that there are very few "simple" libraries out there. Any library powerful enough to do general GIS will unfortunately have a learning curve. That said, [Shapefiles](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) aren't that complicated and there's a lot of code [out there](http://shapelib.maptools.org/) for references purposes.